# how to refer to integer value from xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-asynctask

in the below code, getstatus() method returns an integer ranges between 10,11,12,13. each integer represents a specific bluetooth power state.
i declared those integeres in the strings.xml, and when i refere to one of those integers referenced from the xml file in the while-loop as shown below 
i receive an error saying "Must be one of the bluetooth states", but when i explicitly use integer in condition i receive no errors as shown in the code below

now i want to refer to the integer value from the xml file,  how can i do that correctly

**CODE**:

```
while (!isCancelled() && (mBTAdapter.getState() != getApplicationContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.int_power_state_on)) && (mWaitTime > 0)) {
        //this doe snot work, gives an error
    }

while (!isCancelled() && (mBTAdapter.getState() != 12) && (mWaitTime > 0)) {
        //this one works
    }
```

**XML**

```
<!-- BT Adapter Power States -->
<integer name="int_power_state_turning_off">10</integer>
<integer name="int_power_state_turning_on">11</integer>
<integer name="int_power_state_on">12</integer>
<integer name="int_power_state_off">13</integer>
```

Comment: What happens if you log the value of getApplicationContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.int_power_state_on)?  Is it what you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, it displays the expected value

Comment: Is there any reason why you would use the constants defined in in BluetoothAdapter, such as this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#STATE_OFF   Do you really need a resource for this?

Comment: would u  please tell me why not to use resources for that?and aslo i would like to know how to fix such error in general

Comment: Don't use resources because they're not necessary.  Just use the constants from the class I linked.

Comment: @DougStevenson, ok i will do that, but i have another question which is may be nor pertained to the question posted..is there any advantage to use the hexa constant over the integer constant??why there is a hexa constants?

Comment: Don't type the number you see there, refer to the constant by its name in the doc. This is basIc Java.